# How do I animate scroll on a mobile webbrowser using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, mobile-browser

What I wan't to achieve is the page to scroll to a certain position when a button is pressed. I have this working on browsers like Chrome and IE but it doesn't seem to work on any mobile browser.

This is the code I use:

```
$("#programmaMenu").on("click", "div", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+$(this).attr("rel")).position().top - 120
        }, 500, 'swing');
});
```

The event does fire, only the scrolling doesn't occur.

Comment: Try selecting both `html` and `body` elements: `$('html, body')`

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With thanks to the user [vohuman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848164/undefined), this is the answer:

Apparently mobile browsers scroll the body element and desktop browsers scroll the html element. Therefor, the solution to the question is selecting both the elements 'html' and 'body' like so:

```
$("#programmaMenu").on("click", "div", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+$(this).attr("rel")).position().top - 120
        }, 500, 'swing');
});
```

Comment: what is the use of `.stop()` here

Comment: Stop stops the previous animation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and try,

```
    $(document).on("click", "#programmaMenu", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+$(this).attr("rel")).position().top - 120
    }, 500, 'swing');
    });
```

Comment: The event does fire, only the scrolling doesn't occur. I'll update the question

Comment: Ok. Try to add html, body in the selector for jquery.  $('html, body').stop().animate({});
Or else you can try removing swing parameter from the function